# How to print contents of column fields that have strings composed of "n" character/s using bash?

Tags: linux, string, shell, unix, awk

Say I have a file which contains:

```
22  30  31  3a  31  32  3a  32          " 0 9 : 1 2 : 2
30  32  30  20  32  32  3a  31          1 2 7   2 2 : 1
```

And, I want to print only the column fields that have string composed of 1 character. I want the output to be like this:

```
" 0 9 : 1 2 : 2
1 2 7   2 2 : 1
```

Then, I want to print only those strings that are composed of two characters, the output should be:

```
22  30  31  3a  31  32  3a  32
30  32  30  20  32  32  3a  31
```

I am a beginner and I really don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But 2nd line doesn't have `"` then on what basis we are segregating it, please elaborate more.

Comment: Are those columns tab-separated?

Comment: @Shawn Space and Tab  sir

Comment: Space AND tab? That makes the column with what appears to be a space in the second line kind of hard to accommodate...

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I honestly don't get what you mean sir.. sorry.. What's the problem of having a " in the first row? please enlighten me sir..

Comment: @LiPo, I meant what is the logic of getting them separated, I saw your previous comments on it, no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, I am trying it in a different way for provided samples. Written and tested with provided samples only.

For getting values before BULK SPACE try:

```
awk '
{
  line=$0
  while(match($0,/[[:space:]]+/)){
    arr=arr>RLENGTH?arr:RLENGTH
    start[arr]+=RSTART+prev_start
    prev_start=RSTART
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  var=substr(line,1,start[arr]-1)
  sub(/ +$/,"",var)
  print var
  delete start
  var=arr=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
22  30  31  3a  31  32  3a  32
30  32  30  20  32  32  3a  31
```

---

---

For getting values after BULK SPACE try:

```
awk '
{
  line=$0
  while(match($0,/[[:space:]]+/)){
    arr=arr>RLENGTH?arr:RLENGTH
    start[arr]+=RSTART+prev_start
    prev_start=RSTART
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  var=substr(line,start[arr])
  sub(/^ +/,"",var)
  print var
  delete start
  var=arr=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
" 0 9 : 1 2 : 2
1 2 7   2 2 : 1
```

Comment: The first awk output was those strings that are composed of two characters. While the second awk output was those only composed of single character. Thanks sir @RavinderSingh13 it worked too!

Comment: @LiPo, Sorry that was a typo :) code is working fine, lemme know, it should be flexible solution IMHO for samples provided, Lemme know on same.

Comment: The answer is great in the sense it is robust for the length of whitespaces between the left half and the right. If I were the OP, I would switch to accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah I already switched to this answer. Thanks for all of your efforts :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if(length($i)==1)printf("%s ", $i);print("")}'
```

For each field, check the length and print it if it's desired. You may pass the `-F` option to `awk` if it's not separated by blanks.

The `awk` script is expanded as:

```
for( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i )
  if( length( $i ) == 1 )
    printf( "%s ", $i );
print( "" );
```

The `print` outside loop is to print a newline after each input line.

Comment: Although the answer is accepted by the OP, I'm afraid it does not output
the OP's expected result. The columns after "whitespace" are shifted to
left in the 2nd line.
The file looks like a dump list (hexadecimal values in the left half
and ascii characters in the right half) then it will better to split them with the column position, not the character-length criteria.

Comment: @tshiono you are actually right sir. But, in my case, i don't care if it automatically shifted towards left. As long as it prints my desired strings.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 But, I have to acknowledge, yours was the better answer sir. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the columns are tab-separated (So you can have a space as a column value like the second line of your sample), easy to do with a perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -F"\t" -lane 'BEGIN { $, = "\t" } print grep { /^.$/ } @F' foo.txt
"       0       9       :       1       2       :       2
1       2       7               2       2       :       1
$ perl -F"\t" -lane 'BEGIN { $, = "\t" } print grep { /^..$/ } @F' foo.txt
22      30      31      3a      31      32      3a      32
30      32      30      20      32      32      3a      31
```

Comment: It didn't work for space separated section. But, it worked on those tab separated. Thanks sir @Shawn!